# How add "cover"/"shadow" on div?

Tags: css

I want add "shadow"/"cover" (I'm not sure how to name it) to my div, with css.

cover on:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/842/shadowon.png/

cover off:

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/502/shadowoff.png/

I can do it with an additional div using the `background-image` property where a png file with a small opacity is used. But I want solve this issue with css.

It is possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest something like that:

```
​<div class="image">
    <img src="http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg502/scaled.php?server=502&filename=shadowoff.png&res=landing">
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

and

```
    .image {background: #000; width: 145px; height: 104px;}
    .image img {-webkit-transition: all 1s;}
    .image:hover img {opacity: 0.8;}
```

You can add some CSS3 transitions do make animation smooth :) http://jsfiddle.net/pRbfT/1/

Comment: Thanks, but I have wrote in my post I don't want use addition div. But maybe this is good idea :)

Comment: I don't think you can do it with only <img> tag. box-shadow doesn't work, beacuse opacity on hover will make transparent whole element with all properties. But I'll be glad to see such soultion :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css3 property, which is gradient, to achieve the effect. To make things simpler, you can use css3 generator like this one: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/
You can also use box-shadow with inner shadow settings, to enchance the effect.

Keep in mind that old browsers won't support the feature.

Comment: Thanks, but can I make that shadow be under div?

Answer (score 0):

It seams that it's solid color so you can put transparent div on top of the image.

```
<div class="image_wrapper">
   <div class="cover"/>
   <img src="someimage.png"/>
</div>
```

and use this css

```
.image_wrapper {
   position: relative;
   float: left;
}
.image_wrapper .cover {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   opacity: 0.2;
   background-color: #000;
}
.image_wrapper:hover .cover {
   display: block;
}
```

In Old IE, hover over non `a` tag will not work so you can use `a` instead of `div` for `image_wrapper`
If you want cross browser opacity you can use this

```
  -khtml-opacity:.20;
  -moz-opacity:.20;
  -ms-filter:”alpha(opacity=20)”;
  filter:alpha(opacity=20);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.2);
  opacity:.20;
```